# I got my merit badge, now how do I get back?

Tags: psychonauts

When you reach the PSI level required to unlock a new ability, you can use the bacon to pause whatever you're doing and train it immediately.

How do you *get back there*, however? I was in the middle of Lungfishopolis and the entry point to that is well within the depths of the semi-dry lake floor. I can't just walk back there.

Comment: Have you tried using the bacon *again?*

Comment: He threatens me saying that if I use it in his general neighbourhood, he's going to eat it.

Comment: I think he can teleport you back if you talk to him or use the bacon again (perhaps not right in his presence) but it's been a long time.

Comment: You can access lungfishopolis from the group unconscious. I'm just looking into another question atm. Will form an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that to get his attention I need to simply walk to him and press <kbd>F</kbd> to use it on him. You then get the option "I'm ready to go back into the field."

The problem is that if you have an item equipped and press <kbd>F</kbd>, what will happen is you will use *that item* on Agent Cruller. You can unwield your item by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>.